# d3.js zoom+pan center changed

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming

I am learning d3.js, and I found [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999). I have made a few changes, nothing fancy. However, I wanted to add a zoom to it, and that caused a lot of trouble.

Here is what I have so far (code is also available below): https://fiddle.jshell.net/4w65nbq9/3/

(see comments for what I did and want to do)

I am using this method to zoom and pan:

```
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + "," + d3.event.translate[1] + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")}))
```

It works great, however when I first used the zoom or pan, the whole svg would center back to the (0,0) coordinates.

I found out that the below attribute was responsible for centering the svg in the first place (see comments for changes I made or want to make):

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + radius*1.5 + "," + radius + ")")
```

So when I'd zoom, this part of the code would be voided, and the center would become (0,0).

I then used this code snippet, but put it on the "Links" part of the svg, which would center the links part, and not recenter wrongly after zoom.

What I want to do now, is to center the text the same way (they are generated in the "nodes" section. There is an attribute that generates the placement of each text.

My question is how can I center the texts aswell, so the zoom/pan works correctly, or how can I make the svg not recenter at (0,0). If this method of zooming/panel doesn't work, which one should I use (I want infinite zoom/dezoom, not a max/min).

Here is the same code, but with the links recentered, and the texts not centered: https://fiddle.jshell.net/hanjcupg/1/

The below code has had its style removed to make it shorter (see comments):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>

var file = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/1044242/raw/8f22cf2264e1f6ec6cb233c4b49333fb8f75bb99/readme-flare-imports.json",
    fileinternet = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/1044242/raw/8f22cf2264e1f6ec6cb233c4b49333fb8f75bb99/readme-flare-imports.json",
    fileregular = "data.json",
    isLineActive = false,
    //originally 0.85
    tension = 0.85,
    //originally 960
    diameter = 900,
    radius = diameter / 2,
    innerRadius = radius - 120;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([360, innerRadius])
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .interpolate("bundle")
    .tension(tension)
    .radius(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .angle(function(d) { return d.x / 180 * Math.PI; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter*1.5)
    .attr("height", diameter)
    .attr("style", "outline: thin solid grey;")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + "," + d3.event.translate[1] + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
      }))
  .append("g")
    /*.attr("transform", "translate(" + radius*1.5 + "," + radius + ")")*/;

var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");

d3.json(file, function(error, classes) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var nodes = cluster.nodes(packageHierarchy(classes)),
      links = packageImports(nodes);

  link = link
      .data(bundle(links))
    .enter().append("path")
      .each(function(d) { d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1]; })
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", line)
      //added the transform here to center the links
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius*1.5 + "," + radius + ")");

  node = node
      .data(nodes.filter(function(n) { return !n.children; }))
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius*1.5 + "," + radius + ")")
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("dy", ".31em") 
      //I suppose this is where I need to change the transform to somehow center the nodes, but keep the way it's generated   
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
      .on("click", mouseovered);
});

function mouseovered(d) {
  if (isLineActive) {
    link
      .classed("link--target", false)
      .classed("link--source", false);

    node
      .classed("node--target", false)
      .classed("node--source", false);
    isLineActive = false;
  }
  else {
    node
      .each(function(n) { n.target = n.source = false; });

    link
      .classed("link--target", function(l) { if (l.target === d) return l.source.source = true; })
      .classed("link--source", function(l) { if (l.source === d) return l.target.target = true; })
      .filter(function(l) { return l.target === d || l.source === d; })
      .each(function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); });

    node
      .classed("node--target", function(n) { return n.target; })
      .classed("node--source", function(n) { return n.source; });
  }

}

function mouseouted(d) {
  link
      .classed("link--target", false)
      .classed("link--source", false);

  node
      .classed("node--target", false)
      .classed("node--source", false);
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

function packageHierarchy(classes) {
  var map = {};

  function find(name, data) {
    var node = map[name], i;
    if (!node) {
      node = map[name] = data || {name: name, children: []};
      if (name.length) {
        node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
        node.parent.children.push(node);
        node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
      }
    }
    return node;
  }

  classes.forEach(function(d) {
    find(d.name, d);
  });

  return map[""];
}

function packageImports(nodes) {
  var map = {},
      imports = [];

  // Compute a map from name to node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    map[d.name] = d;
  });

  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
      imports.push({source: map[d.name], target: map[i]});
    });
  });

  return imports;
}

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. The simple solution was to add an extra .append(g) after the svg transform like so:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter*1.5)
    .attr("height", diameter)
    .attr("style", "outline: thin solid grey;")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + "," + d3.event.translate[1] + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
    }))
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius*1.5 + "," + radius + ")")
    //this is the part that I added.
    .append("g")
```